Does incorporating lower bound on dependent variable improve estimation?
Suppose we flip a coin $K$ times, where $Z_k = 1$ if heads otherwise 0, and $Y = \sum_{k=1}^{K} Z_k$ is the total number of heads. Assume that these are i.i.d. fair coins and $P(Z_k=1) = 0.5$.
We then repeat this game $n$ times, flipping $K$ coins each time and observing a realization $Y_i$. The goal is to predict the number of heads in each game $\{Y_i : i=1,\dots, n\}$.

Since we know the distribution $Y \sim Binom(K, 0.5)$, the standard/"naive" way is simply the mean estimator:
$$ \hat{Y}_i = \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0.5K$$
which gives constant predictions for each of the $n$ games.
Now the question is as follows. Suppose we are at the $i$th game. At any point before $K$ flips we can pause the game, refine our model, and resume the rest of the flips. Can we improve upon the naive estimator?
An oracle estimator would set $\hat{Y}_i = Y_i$ with $MSE(Y_i, \hat{Y}_i) = 0$, but this is obviously impossible in practice since we don't actually know what the outcome is. However with each coin flip, we collect more information on a lower bound on $Y_i$. More precisely if we pause the flips and observe that there have been $c_i$ heads, then we know
$$ Y_i \geq c_i $$
This then motivates the "augmented" estimator:
$$ \hat{Y}_i^{aug}(c_i) = \mathbb{E}[Y|Y\geq c_i] = \frac{ \int_{c_i}^{K} y \ dP_Y}{\int_{c_i}^{K} dP_Y} = \frac{\sum_{y=c_i}^{K} y P(Y=y)}{P(Y \geq c_i)}$$
where the naive estimator is a special case of $c_i = 0$. Taking the interpretation of the conditioning $\sigma$-algebra as information, we have gained some additional information on each $Y_i$ which should presumably allow us to get better predictions. For example, suppose $K=10$ and we paused the game after $c=6$ flips. The naive estimator would predict $\hat{Y}_i = 5$. But we already know that $Y_i \geq 6$, so any prediction above 6 would be closer to the true $Y_i$ than the naive estimator.
Is there a way to formally prove that the augmented estimator is "better" in some sense than the naive estimator?

I ran a numerical simulation with $K=10$ and got some interesting results. The x-axis here is letting $c = pY$ for $p \in [0,1]$. As $c$ increases, we obtain more "partial knowledge" about $Y$. It makes sense intuitively that the more information we have, the lower the MSE and better our predictions, however the U-shaped phenomena is interesting.


Could you clarify what it means to "have some additional data" on a lower bound for $T$?  What form do those data take--or are you really trying to say you are imposing an additional assumption on the marginal distribution of $T$?

I'm still thinking of how to formally frame the problem, but I think the bus example illustrates the point. My goal is to predict the bus waiting time $T$ given $X$, and the typical conditional mean estimator would be analogous to making a prediction once the bus leaves the depot, and seeing how long it takes to arrive at the bus station.
However now we are sitting at the bus station. With every $t$ minutes that pass, we can observe that the bus has not arrived and therefore this particular realization must satisfy $T_i \geq t$.

@whuber I've completely rewritten the problem. Let me know if it is unclear in some way.
